# Css styling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm working on this project (http://www.leapfm.com/)  and I've been gathering feedback. One point was:

> the 1 like, posted 5 days... bit is further away from the link it is
>   connected to than the link below it. "James Blake - Retrograde" -> 1
>   like -> looks like it could belong to "Paris - Magic Man"

But I'm having trouble fixing that putting a padding: 0; on the subtext class isn't working.

How can this be done?

Code snippit (pretty sure it's on this element):

```
.subtext {
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 7pt;
color: #828282;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the bit of code where the problem is? Just a link is a bit unclear.

Comment: sure, one sec (will edit original post) but you can also use 'inspect element' or 'firebug'

Comment: not sure..text-index:-xx px..negative index may work..but not sure...if you give us a fiddle it would be great

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xsRJ9/

Comment: i think you did not show us the problem in your fiddle

Comment: that line of code is where the problem lies. In the 'likes' line which is wrapped in the subtext class. I'd just like it to be closer to the link/song it belongs to. So if you look at www.leapfm.com. You'll see James Blake and then under it 1 like, i'd like to move the 1 like line closer under James blake

Comment: i think `position:relative;top:2px;` or `margin-top:-ve px;` may work..

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34799/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18045704-css-styling-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from that your HTML markup is terrible wrong, for example you can not have a `li` tag within a `span` tag. Check your site out at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.leapfm.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0.

You can not add `margin` and `padding` to a `span` without it being a block object.
If you add `display:block` to your `.subtext` it will sit closer to your title and can have more `margin` at the bottom.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, instead of looking for a quick dirty fix it's better to write good code.

Answer (score 1):

add below code to your `.subtext`

```
position:relative;
top:-10px;
```

EXAMPLE:: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xsRJ9/1/)**

Comment: that is a css hack, not an useful solution.